# Rails - passing extra parameters through a link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, if-statement, hyperlink, conditional-statements

I have two tables in my application. The user table and the activities - the user has many activities (3 in total to be exact).

I have a home page with 3 buttons on it. If the user presses button one, I want to navigate to the activities index page and set the attribute activity_type to = 1. If the user presses button 2,  I want to navigate to the activities index page and  set the activity_type to = 2 etc. Right now I have:

```
<%= link_to 'Personal Activity', user_activities_path(:user_id => current_user.id, :activity_type => 1) %>
<%= link_to 'Physical Activity', user_activities_path(:user_id => current_user.id, :activity_type => 2) %>
<%= link_to 'Community Activity', user_activities_path(:user_id => current_user.id, :activity_type => 3) %>
```

In my activities/index.html.erb file I want to have three conditions:

```
If the activity_type = 1 for current_user
  Do X
Elsif the activity_type = 2 for current_user
  Do Y
Else
  Do X
End
```

It doesn't seem to be recognising the activity_type parameter I have included in the link. How do I do this?

Comment: How did you tried fetching `activity_type`? like `params[:activity_type]`?

Comment: Right now I have this in my index view: <%= if current_user.activities.activity_type == 1 %> . I'm not sure where I would fetch the activity_type from or where I use params[:activity_type]?

Comment: Are those links navigating to index page? If so `params[:activity_type]` should work

Answer (score 1):

If those links really taking you to the `index` page, then you can access `activity_type` with `params[:activity_type]`. Also I recommend you to put the logic in the `controller#action`.

```
def index
  @activity_type = params[:activity_type]

  case @activity_type
  when 1
    #your logic
  when 2
    #your logic
  when 3
    #your logic
  else
    #some code
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

These parameters are appended to params and you can access them like these:

```
activity_type = params[:activity_type]
```

or simply like this:

```
if params[:activity_type] == 1
  Do something
else
  Do something
end
```